# Color midrule in tabularx

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

I have created a table using tabularx. Can I color the `\midrule` instead of having it colored black as default?

Comment: doesn't `\arrayrulecolor{blue}` from `colortbl` work? If not edit the question to have a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Apparently you still have not understood how this site works: Provide a MWE

Comment: It really would make it much easier to help if you would provide a minimum working example. For example `\midrule` is not defined by `tabularx` and is not a standard LaTeX command either. There are many, many, many packages so people do not necessarily know which packages your question requires - never mind issues to do with your choice of document class. In this particular case, many users will recognise `\midrule` as coming from `booktabs` but that is just because it is a popular package and a frequently-used command. A user new to LaTeX would not be much helped by your question, either. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx, colortbl} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{XXX}
\arrayrulecolor{red}  % choose color
aaaa & bbbb & cccc\\
\midrule
xxxx & yyyy & zzzz\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That would color all `booktabs` rules, right?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Not just the `booktabs` rules...

Comment: Oh, right. Doesn't seem like a good idea to redefine that :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B - Currently, the redefinition's scope is the `tabularx` environment. The scope can be narrowed down further, naturally. Without an MWE or other piece of information from the OP, it's not possible to be too specific about the correct course of action.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that :-)